# Invalid STATDATA

Tags: wpf, com, ole

A customer is running our WPF Application which does call a COM object (in case this is relevant) and they are getting an "Invalid STATDATA" error.
DV_E_STATDATA 0x80040067

Can't find anything about it except on websites that advertise Windows Cleanup utilities.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: do you have a stack trace corresponding to this exception?

Comment: No. It is only happening with a single customer and in code, we have a try/catch around the method call and it is dumping the exception into a log file.

Comment: Well, you should modify your code so it dumps the whole exception (`ex.ToString()`), not only the exception's message.